Is it possible to modify an EEG cap to accomodate fNIRS 'channels'?
I'm doing a project with several students, and we are trying to record EEG and fNIRS data simultaneously. We do have an EEG device, and are looking around our university for fNIRS devices. We currently don't know how are we going to place our fNIRS electrodes (sources and detectors).
The moment we get an fNIRS device, we will, of course, try and see if our own EEG cap can accommodate the fNIRS electrodes. However, failing that, are there possible modifications we can do to accomodate the electrodes?
We have also checked available products in the market. Many companies sell caps that can accomodate both EEG and fNIRS, g.TEC, NIRX, Brain Products, Artinis, etc. What we're not sure about is whether their cap will work with the electrodes that we (will) have.
From the literature I've encountered, people seem to use commercial devices that have were intentionally meant to record EEG+fNIRS simultaneously, so they don't have to make custom modifications.
Question: Are there possible modifications/tricks to an EEG cap so that it can also accomodates fNIRS sources & detectors?

afaik, buying a combo device is common practice, because you cannot place two caps on the head and also because you need to sync the recordings of both devices I guess

@AliceD eh, from the literature I've seen the 'hybridization' is often concatenating EEG features with fNIRS features. I don't think they have to be 100% in sync for this case. OTOH, I've seen some papers where the two data are truely fused, using fNIRS as priors for EEG source localization. Now I figure would require a combo device.

Makes sense, but from the limited experience I have in the field, it's quite commonplace to buy the systems as an integrated approach

@AliceD Do you know of such integrated devices? I have only found ISS Imagent and NIRX NIRScout. A few other brands market an "EEG+fNIRS package", but is essentially selling an integrated cap and two separate recording devices. The more integrated devices I am aware of, the higher the chance I encounter one when browsing through my university's inventory.
